# Sklean RandomForest Get OOB Sample

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

I'm a newbie in Scikit-learn. I'm working with RandomForest

Please how could I get the OOB Samble for each tree of the forest ?

```
RANDOM_STATE = 1708
clf = RandomForestClassifier(warm_start=True, oob_score=True,
                               max_features=None,
                               random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
clf.fit(KDD_data, y)

# Loop through the list of tree of the forest
for tree in clf.estimators_:
    # Get sample used to build the tree

    # Get the OOB sample for that tree
```

I would like to get the sample used to build each tree of the forest and the remaining out of bag sample.

How to get it please ?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the documentation, it doesn't seem like scikit-learn exposes this functionality. Looking at the documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html), oob_score can be measured on a per-RandomForestClassifier basis. Each tree that you are looping through is a DecisionTreeClassifier, and in looking at the documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) for DecisionTreeClassifiers there's no way to get oob_score on a DecisionTreeClassifier. Furthermore, I don't think it would be valid to have an oob_score on a DecisionTreeClassifier (judging by [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-out-of-bag-error-in-Random-Forests) definition of oob error).

Your other question of how to get the sample used to construct the tree seems valid, but I also don't see a method or attribute exposed by scikit-learn that would allow you to access the sample used to construct the tree.